# Make an image inside a div act like a background image cover

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Trying to have an inline image auto crop inside a div to simulate a background image. I tried using absolute position with a size larger than 100% but when you resize it works for the height one time and then breaks for the width another. I am assuming the square shape doesn't help any. Do you have any suggestions on how to resolve this result?

[image]

Is JavaScript the best way to make this work?

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  background: #ccc;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.col-md-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x500/500/fff" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis officia animi consectetur obcaecati cum harum aliquam qui nisi aliquid sint. Nobis voluptas sequi voluptatem soluta ex sed nisi, sapiente dicta!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

Comment: Can you just use `background-image` in the CSS?

Comment: I agree with @DrydenLong - plus, there are a few `background-size` options to use: I tend to go for `background-size: cover` and then `background-position: center`; how you do it is up to you :)

Comment: I tried that but since the image is inside a floated div the column heights don't match. As you resize  the window the column goes from a square to a rectangle. So maybe I have to swap images at the breakpoint.

Comment: Do you want your image to be the background of its immediate parent (`<div class="col-md-6">`)? This might be tricky, as the bootstrap `col` classes use float

Comment: @geoffJames yes exactly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19695784/how-can-i-make-bootstrap-columns-all-the-same-height

Comment: Good shout @DaniP - I'll be bookmarking that link for future reference! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've just had a play with your CodePen code.

This *might* help/be what you want:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6 background-cover-image">
          <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x500/500/fff" class="img-responsive" style="opacity: 0;" />
      </div>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
      <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
          Officiis officia animi consectetur obcaecati cum harum aliquam qui nisi aliquid sint.
          Nobis voluptas sequi voluptatem soluta ex sed nisi, sapiente dicta!</p>
      </div>
      <!-- Apply clearfix to stop other content floating up over -->
      <i class="clearfix" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
   </div>
   <!-- /.row -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
body {background:#000;}
.container {background:#ccc;}
.row {border:1px solid #fff;}
.col-md-6 {border:1px solid red;} // All of these are as before :)

.background-cover-image {
   background-image: url('http://dummyimage.com/600x500/500/fff');
   background-size: cover;
   background-position: center;
}
```

The secret here, is that the original image is still there (with its `opacity` set to `0`), so it's still "there", and gives the `div` some height. *Please do not use in-line styles, like I have; move them to a CSS class - I've just done it for the example!.*

It works fine for me - however you will need to decide when the background image div (or whatever you'd like to call it) positions itself *above* the other content.

Note the use of the `clearfix` class in the `<i>` tag, just so that the content beneath doesn't float up and into this lot. *You might also want to use the `clearfix` in other `div`s - very useful class! :)*

Any questions, just ask.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: +1 super clever changing the opacity. I was working on some JS trickery, but this seems like a better solution to me...

Comment: Thank you very much Geoff James. This looks like it will work and I really like your use of the inline image to set the height. I have seen a similar technique with owl carousel and I think the cycle2 plugin of a transparent placeholder. Must do the same type of thing. The only addition I am going to make is to add the background img url via javascript to make it more CMS friendly.

Comment: Pleasure's all mine :) Good note with the JS modifying the background image for reusable code. I'll add some sample JS when I get a chance (it's late and I'm on the mobile app) - just for future-comers. **As an aside thought** - how about only changing the `opacity` of the original `<img>` tag from your JS, once you've set the background of the parent? This will mean when the page is rendered; mainly for browsers with scripting turned off, your image will still be visible (until (if) the script runs, switching it to a background img etc.).

Comment: Here is an all javascript solution to work well with a CMS. If the user has javascript disabled it will fallback to the image. So it is a win/win. Thanks again Geoff. http://codepen.io/JacobLett/pen/gMgOBj

Comment: I'm glad you got what I meant with my last suggestion - it was late at night! And you've saved my little brain with that CodePen JS you've written - been a lonnnnng day! *sigh*. Hats off to you @JacobLett - Best regards to you in your project :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding it as background-image style to it's parent div.

```css
body {
  background: #000;
}
.container {
  background: #ccc;
}
.row {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
}
.col-md-6 {
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.image-holder {
  background: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.img-responsive {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 image-holder" style="background-image:url(http://dummyimage.com/600x500/500/fff);">
      <img src="http://dummyimage.com/600x500/500/fff" class="img-responsive" />
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h2>Heading</h2>

      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Officiis officia animi consectetur obcaecati cum harum aliquam qui nisi aliquid sint. Nobis voluptas sequi voluptatem soluta ex sed nisi, sapiente dicta!</p>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-md-6 -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.row -->

</div>
```

Comment: Hmm... I like your approach with the JS copying the url attribute. I'm afraid I don't like that the `image` and `image-holder` classes both have fixed heights of `350px` - the idea of setting the image to be `responsive` is completely counter-productive to this code

Comment: Also (and I'm being pedantic here - excuse me), your `no-repeat` declaration when the size is `cover` is redundant, as it would never be smaller than the container (it's `cover`ing it)

Comment: Removed the js part and the `image` class. There's no fixed height now.

Comment: Ok fair enough. But now you've `display: none` the `img-responsive` class the div will have no height at all (plus this would break ALL other `img-responsive`s if it's set in a stylesheet and used site-wide). And I did say I **like** your JS approach; but now you've removed it :( Also, when you had the image still visible in the DOM (and not `display: none`), the image itself would still appear over the top of the background image of the div